# Filter collections in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a Laravel collection of designs:

```
"xdo45ttnqhsb" => array:5 [▼
      "design_id" => "xdo45ttnqhsb"
      "design_name" => "hufflepuff house"
      "category" => "harry potter"
      "tags" => array:6 [▶]
      "article_owner" => "1728"
    ]
    "wpy8r2erkk2t" => array:5 [▼
      "design_id" => "wpy8r2erkk2t"
      "design_name" => "ravenclaw house"
      "category" => "harry potter"
      "tags" => array:6 [▶]
      "article_owner" => "1728"
    ]
    "8oy7sb7i98q0" => array:5 [▼
      "design_id" => "8oy7sb7i98q0"
      "design_name" => "be positive friend"
      "category" => "miscelanea"
      "tags" => array:5 [▶]
      "article_owner" => "1728"
    ]
    "a9m79qc6bl9x" => array:5 [▼
      "design_id" => "a9m79qc6bl9x"
      "design_name" => "final fantasy pixel"
      "category" => "pixelart"
      "tags" => array:5 [▶]
      "article_owner" => "1728"
    ]
```

I want to take designs that belong to a single category.

For example: I need to get only the designs with "category" with the value "harry potter".

What collection helper could I use for this?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the `->filter()` method which should work well for you.

```
$collection->filter(function($arr){
    return $arr['category'] = "harry potter";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [laravel collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections) and based on my knowledge, you can filter the records with `filter()` and you code with `filter()` look like below snippet:

```
$collection->filter(function ($arrValue, $key) {
   return (isset($arrValue['category']) && $arrValue['category'] == "harry potter");
});
```

Hope this help you to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `filter()` as others suggested or use:

`$collection->where('category', '=', 'harry potter')->get()`

Which will return a collection of items in the previous collection that `category` equals to `harry potter`.